# How to reslice an image in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage

I am often a bit silly when I try to slice resizable images, and end up in this situation:

[image: xcode screenshot]

As you can see, I've done a 9-slice on the top image, and a 3-slice on the bottom. And yet, Xcode doesn't let me back out of this. My option seems to be deleting and then re-adding the image. But is there a way do re-specify slicing within Xcode?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While in slicing view, select the image you are want to reset (click on its title) and open the attributes inspector in the right sidebar (⌥⌘4). Under "Slicing" you can change slicing parameters, and even disable it.